# Complex Nested dictionary

Tags: python, python-2.7

I want to create a nested dictionary in Python such that:

```
Dict -> list of dict -> list
```

eg:

```
dict = { a : [{a1 : [00, 01]}, {a2 : [1, 0]}]
         b : [{b1 : [2, 3]}, {b2 : [4, 5]}]
       }
```

I believe I can use `defaultdict`, but I'm not sure how to.

Comment: The obvious solution from the wording of your post, is to work through one or two tutorials on DefaultDict.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, this code is for you:

```
d = { 'a' : [{'a1' : [0, 1]}, {'a2' : [1, 0]}],
      'b' : [{'b1' : [2, 3]}, {'b2' : [4, 5]}]}
```